# Measuring multi-dimensional array similarity

Tags: computational-statistics, similarities, distance-functions

I have several multiple dimensional (1364x6) arrays which are gathered using a sliding window over a fixed size image (the values are mean of the intensity in each of the channels).

```
shape= (1364, 6)
[[ 220.0234375   222.390625    225.62109375   69.02682504   68.32753544
    67.59559915]
 [ 246.94140625  247.5625      248.6640625    14.0323456    11.6798103
    11.37175595]
 ..., 

 [ 196.07176208  196.12571716  195.89080811   94.62852155   94.81147332
    94.76462336]]
```

What are the best of doing pairwise similarity using this dataset and infer closest images from them?

I was trying to hash them (md5), but not seeing good results. I have heard of MinHash and SimHash but not sure how I could go about using them for this case?

would looping over the rows x cols and compute cosine similarity be mathematically correct?

All suggestions very welcome!

Comment: Your question may be starting at the wrong level: If you are "not seeing good results", how do you know if the problem is the feature-similarity measure vs. the features? I am no expert here, but moving averages seem like they may not be very discriminative.

Comment: @GeoMatt22: I know because I am generating the features from similar images and dissimilar images (so I have the "groundtruth")/

Comment: I am not sure how that is relevant? It is *very* possible to generate features which are similar from images which are different. (In many cases this is *desirable*, and called "invariance".) I am not saying that is the case here, only that it perhaps *could* be.